# Testing thread priority. How come in some cases low priority threads are faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

I'm trying to test 2 threads, one with high, and the other with low priority.

According to my results sometimes the low priority thread is faster, how is this possible?
I've tested the different priority threads by increment a click variable inside each thread.
I've also increased and decreased the sleep time, but nothing.

Since I was testing with no heavy programs running in the background, I decided to test with an HD movie running, but still no real change, threads are always the same speed.

My PC is an Intel i5. I'm running Windows 7 64bit, 16GB RAM

### This is the code:

```
class clicker implements Runnable{
    long click =0;
    Thread t;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    clicker(int p){
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(p);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(running)
            click++;
    }

    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public void start(){
        t.start();
    }
}




class HiLoPri {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    clicker hi=new clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+4);
    clicker lo=new clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-4);

    lo.start();
    hi.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lo.stop();
    hi.stop();

    try {
        hi.t.join();
        lo.t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("LO: "+lo.click);
    System.out.println("HI: "+hi.click);
 }  
}
```

Comment: You're using fewer threads than you have processor cores, if nothing else is running and consuming significant resources, why would you expect priority to matter at all?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml http://vanillajava.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/why-thread-priority-rarely-matters.html are good explanations of what can make java threading priority not seem to matter

Comment: As specified by @Affe, your testcase is not big enough. Try running more threads. (I see you updated your question after adding some background load from different processes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.  One is that threads take a while to start, so you're giving "Low" a pretty good head start by firing them off serially.  The other is that thread priority decides who gets to run when there's an argument for processor time.  With two threads and 8 effective processor cores, priority isn't going to matter a whole lot!  Here is a fixed example that uses a latch to start all threads as "simultaneously" and uses enough threads that they actually fight over resources and you can see the effect of priority settings.  It gives pretty consistent results.

```
static class Clicker implements Runnable{
    BigInteger click = BigInteger.ZERO;
    Thread t;

    Clicker(int p){
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(p);
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
        latch.await();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
        while(running)
            click = click.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    public void start(){
        t.start();
    }
}

public static volatile boolean running = true;
public static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void main(String args[]){
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    List<Clicker> listLow = new ArrayList<Clicker>();
    List<Clicker> listHigh = new ArrayList<Clicker>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        listHigh.add(new Clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+4));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        listLow.add(new Clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-4));
    }
    for (Clicker clicker: listLow) {
        clicker.start();
    }
    for (Clicker clicker: listHigh) {
        clicker.start();
    }
    latch.countDown();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    running = false;

    BigInteger lowTotal = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger highTotal = BigInteger.ZERO;
    try {
        for (Clicker clicker: listLow) {
            clicker.t.join();
            lowTotal = lowTotal.add(clicker.click);
        }
    for (Clicker clicker: listHigh) {
            clicker.t.join();
            highTotal = highTotal.add(clicker.click);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("LO: "+lowTotal);
    System.out.println("HI: "+highTotal);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thread priorities are not guaranteed to have any effect; this is mentioned in multiple places, including JDK javadocs. So assuming that on platform you are running on basically ignores levels, then it goes back to basic stastical probabilities: sometimes some threads seem to run faster than others, depending on how scheduler works and so on.

I don't think anyone really uses Java thread priorities for everything, given that their working (or lack thereof) is at best platform-dependent.

Comment: Just because current support for thread priorities is mediocre doesn't mean it shouldn't be used. I think you should use it where it makes sense but not depend on it (or depend on it not working), since future releases may fix it. (No offense intended, your answer *may* suggest to others that this feature should not be used)

Comment: Let me put it this way: if thread priorities were considered worth fixing, they would have been fixed years ago. That said, sure, if one finds them useful on given platform, yeah why not. I just have never heard of anyone having found them useful for anything.

Comment: Thread base priorities, (as distinct from dynamic priorities where a thread that has just become ready on I/O or inter-thread comms synchro), is only marginally useful in those cases where the box is regularly overloaded, ie. often more ready threads than cores. Very few machines get into that state.