# how to make priority in java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to give priority to thread b but it's not working still sometimes print thread t before b the priority does not work, I am not sure about the code any help please !

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new one("this is t thread"));
    Thread b = new Thread(new one("this is b thread"));

    b.setPriority(10);
    t.setPriority(4);

    t.start();
    b.start();
}    


class one implements Runnable {
    String name;

    public one(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are many problems with this example, but, fundamentally, you called `t.start()` first.  why would it just wait around to see if you start a higher priority thread later?

Comment: Found it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289637/java-testing-thread-priority-how-come-in-some-cases-low-priority-threads-are-f/16289839#16289839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads, even with priority, are independent by design. You cannot guarantee anything without locking.

You could create any object and call it lockObject.

You can then have thread t start, and call `lockObject.wait()` before printing.

Thread b then calls its print and *then* calls `lockObject.notify()` making sure that it's the same instance of the same object(just declare it as `static Object lockObject=new Object()` in your class)

If thread t starts beating thread b, it'll wait for the notification. Before this notification fires, t must have printed.

This is not an optimal method but should be sufficient for this question